# Hosting ArcGIS Services through fully-qualified domain name and servername using ArcGIS Server

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-9.3, references

We currently host an ArcGIS Server 9.3.1 SP2 .NET on our Intranet. A situation has come up that requires me to have the ArcGIS server respond to both the servername and through a fully qualified domain URL to access GIS services.

How do I configure the server to respond to the fully-qualified domain name and servername for ArcGIS requests?

```
http://servername/ArcGIS/rest/Services

http://sub.domain.foo/ArcGIS/rest/services
```

Is there a whitepaper, directions, something that explains how I can fulfill this scenario?

---

Reverse proxy would be ideal and actually after reading through this setup I will be proposing we setup our environment as such going forward.

In the mean time I need to have this particular Silverlight site up and running by Monday morning within our Intranet for remote office access (Secure VPN), using a single domain name where the GIS services can be referenced through the domain name itself.

Now I know I could bind the domain name to the Default Web Site within IIS, setup the Silverlight project, and GIS services and the site should respond as expected. This is the quick and dirty answer to my dilemma for a Monday morning availability.

But for conversation and learning more about the ArcGIS server flexibility - are there any other options to consider?

Answer (score 1):

Esri generally recommends that you configure a reverse proxy to "publish" your ArcGIS Server onto the Internet.

The REST services are stateless so there's no additional configuration that you would need to do on the server running ArcGIS Server itself.

Using a reverse proxy also gives you an opportunity to ensure that only those services that you want to publish are available externally.

See archived content via http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/32634 for more info.